# Is there a function for obtaining JSON attributes that can be passed as parameter?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a powerpoint on functional programming in JS for my workmates (because Java's Streams have too much boilerplate for an intro) and was wondering:
Is there a syntactic sugar for getting an object's attributes without libraries?

In Java you can do: (based on, say, a Person with a name attribute and its getter method)

```
public List<String> names(List<Person> people){
  return people.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

I'm looking for that Person::getName equivalent.

Edit: I was hoping for a workaround for the lambda expression where the function was passed directly as a parameter.

So, instead of `people.map(person => person.name)` , one would put something like `people.map(getName)` or similar.

Comment: like `foo.map({name} => name)` or  `foo.map(person => person.name)`???

Comment: Object properties in JavaScript are just that; they're not "JSON attributes". You can use the `[ ]` operator to access property values by a computed name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, JavaScript doesn't have that<sup>1</sup>, it is customary to just use an arrow function ("lambda" in Java slang):

```
names(people){
  return people.map(p => p.name); // or p => p.getName();
  // or people[Symbol.iterator]().map(…).toArray();
}
```

<sub>1: If you really have a `class Person` with a `getName` prototype method, you can trivially write a helper function `const accessor = method => instance => method.call(instance);` to be used as `.map(accessor(Person.prototype.getName))` but it would not be very idiomatic. At best, for accessing things by property name: `const get = propName => object => object[propName];` and `.map(get("name"))`.</sub>